# AngularJS Terminal Directive Not Working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jmcooper/uPPS5/).
I have been experimenting with directive priorities and the terminal property.  I have created a three directives with priorities 3, 2, and 1.  The main directive (highest priority, priority: 3) has a template that creates a button and clicking the button calls a method on the directive's controller. Everything works fine until I put terminal: true on the priority 2 directive.  For some a reason that causes the button to stop working; the main directive (priority 3) renders fine, but clicking the button does nothing.  Again, here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmcooper/uPPS5/), and here is the code for the directives:

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('greeting', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            priority: 3,
            template: "<button class='btn' ng-click='sayHello()'>Say Hello</button>",
            controller: function($scope) {
                var greetings = ['hello'];
                $scope.sayHello = function() {
                    alert(greetings.join());
                }
                this.addGreeting = function(greeting) {
                    greetings.push(greeting);
                }
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('finnish', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: 2,
            terminal:true,
            require: 'greeting',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                controller.addGreeting('hei');
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('hindi', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: 1,
            require: 'greeting',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                controller.addGreeting('नमस्ते');
            }
        };
    });
```

The html on the page looks like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <greeting finnish hindi />
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debugging the AngularJS code (particularly applyDirectivesToNode [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/48308913bb1b6f2eaa8c1a59348a76e99c14d320/src/ng/compile.js#L592)) it looks like when you set `terminal:true` on your `finnish` directive it ends up halting the processing of `ng-click` (which is itself a directive set to priority  0, lower than priority 2). So clicking on the button does nothing.

[Here is a modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uPPS5/1/) with the priorities of your directives changed to 0, -1, and -2 respectively so as not to terminate the `ng-click`.

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('greeting', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            priority: 0,
            template: "<button class='btn' ng-click='sayHello()'>Say Hello</button>",
            controller: function($scope) {
                var greetings = ['hello'];
                $scope.sayHello = function() {
                    alert(greetings.join());
                }
                this.addGreeting = function(greeting) {
                    greetings.push(greeting);
                }
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('finnish', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: -1,
            terminal:true,
            require: 'greeting',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                controller.addGreeting('hei');
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('hindi', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: -2,
            require: 'greeting',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                controller.addGreeting('नमस्ते');
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: That totally makes sense!  Thank you for digging into that!

Answer (score 0):

@Jim Cooper, if you use Angular-1.2.1, you'll get "hello,hie" as the output on click of the button. I believe that should be the output. Otherwise the priority of the greeting needs to be set according to the priority of the directives that's being used in the templated html. That would be confusing, If we introduce custom directive with different priority inside the templated html along with some built-in directives.